How to integrate Socket.IO in Cocos Project made in Cocos Creator 3.8.3?
I am trying to integrate Socket.IO client in my project developed in Cocos Creator 3.8.3. But every time I try to connect to the server an error appears. My research on the internet and some help with AI couldn't resolve the issue. Please help resolving the issue or suggest what I am doing wrong. This is the error:
(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function


This is my code:
import { _decorator, Component } from 'cc';
import AppConstants from "db://assets/Scripts/Utils/AppConstants";
const { ccclass } = _decorator;
import { io } from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js';

@ccclass('PokerManager')
export class PokerManager extends Component {

     start() {
         this.connectToServer()
    }

    public connectToServer() {
        console.log("Starting connection to socket.io server");
        var socket = io(AppConstants.Api.SocketURL, {
            timeout: 10000,
            transports: ["websocket"],
        });
        socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log(`Socket.ID: ${socket.id}`); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
        });
    }
}

package.json file:
{
  "name": "Poker",
  "uuid": "8443b3c5-dc49-4252-8e42-cd270e183a6d",
  "creator": {
    "version": "3.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"
  }
}

tsconfig.json file:
{
  /* Base configuration. Do not edit this field. */
  "extends": "./temp/tsconfig.cocos.json",

  /* Add your custom configuration here. */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}

